# How to make my data in proper json by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my data in form of:

```
{
    prodName: "parle",
    prodDesc: "The fresh milk biscuits for children",
    prodPrice: "30",
    prodManufacturer: "biscuits"
}
```

I want my data to be in form of:

```
{
    "prodName": "parle",
    "prodDesc": "The fresh milk biscuits for children",
    "prodPrice": "30",
    "prodManufacturer": "biscuits"
}
```

#### My code

```
 var productObject = {
      "name": document.getElementById('productName').value,
      "price":  document.getElementById('productPrice').value,
      "description":document.getElementById('productDescription').value,
      "manufacturer":document.getElementById('productManufacturer').value
    };
    console.log("The Data is ",productObject);
    //var dataForPost = JSON.stringify(productObject);
  $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'http://localhost:8080/products',
        data:JSON.stringify(productObject),
        headers:{
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        crossOrigin:true,
        crossDomain:true,
      });
```

Can any body tell me how to do that?

Comment: `data: productObject,`

Answer (score 1):

you can just create another object with the naming how ever you want

```js
var productObject = {
  "name": "Name",
  "price": 10,
  "description": "Product Description",
  "manufacturer": "Product Manufucturer"
};

var data = {
  prodName: productObject.name,
  prodPrice: productObject.price,
  prodDesc: productObject.description,
  prodManufucturer: productObject.manufacturer
 };
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript object does not have double quoted keys unless you serialize it to JSON.

Your object will get quoted keys when you call `JSON.stringify(obj)`

#### Example

```js
var obj = {
    prodName: "parle",
    prodDesc: "The fresh milk biscuits for children",
    prodPrice: "30",
    prodManufacturer: "biscuits"
};

console.log(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```